# Jest - simulate keydown "ArrowUp" and invoking a function

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I have a component that renders input with controls. The controls act as adding/minusing the value by 1. I have `input` with `onKeyDown={handleKeyDown}`

```
const addUp = () => {
    let next = value + 1;
    if (next > max) {
        next = max;
    }
    setValue(next);
    onChange(next);
};

const minusDown = () => {
    let next = value - 1;
    if (next < min) {
        next = min;
    }
    setValue(next);
    onChange(next);
};


function handleKeyDown() {
    const input = event.currentTarget;
    switch (event.key) {
        case "ArrowUp":
            addUp();
            break;
        case "ArrowDown":
            minusDown();
            break;
    }
    event.preventDefault();
}
```

I want to mock the handleKeyDown above.  Here's what I tried so far:

```
  let defaultProps: Props;
  beforeEach(() => {
      defaultProps = {
          max: 100,
          min: 1,
          onChange: noop,
          value: 10,
      };
  });



describe("controls", () => {
    it("should call addUp and increase value", () => {
        const addUp = jest.fn();
        const wrapper = mount(<MyComponent {...defaultProps} />);
        const input = wrapper.find("input");
        input.simulate("keydown", { key: "ArrowUp", keyCode: 38, preventDefault() {}, which: 38 });

        expect(addUp).toBeCalledTimes(1);
        expect(input.prop("value")).toBe(11);
    });
});
```

this is the error I'm getting:

```
expect(jest.fn()).toBeCalledTimes(expected)

Expected number of calls: 1
Received number of calls: 0
```

Does anyone have any suggestion on how to do this properly?

Answer (score 1):

The `.simulate()` method [is actually deprecated](https://github.com/enzymejs/enzyme/issues/2173#issuecomment-505551552), according to project maintainers.

The suggested solution is to use the component instance's prop handlers that would trigger these events; in this case, that would be `wrapper.props().onKeyDown()`. This should be used instead of `.simulate()`.

Comment: How would I target "ArrowUp" in this case?

Comment: First, you need to provide the `event` parameter in your `handleKeyDown` function definition, so that it can be used in the function body.


```javascript
function handleKeyDown(event) {
  // ...
}
```


Then, provide an `event`-style object with the properties you are accessing in your function body:

```javascript
wrapper.props().onKeyDown({ key: "ArrowUp" })
```